# reusable view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I need to display different data at the different instance in a page with respect a list selection on the same page. Is there any mechanism like fragment is in ios. how to solve this. I need to display a list of horizontal items at the bottom and with respect, the selection the content on the page should be changed​.

Comment: Try using `CollectionView`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. Your question is really about the ***very basics*** of iOS UI design, and is much too broad for any answer other than *"Yes, you can do that, and here are 50 different ways...."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Collection view and in cell of collection-view , you can create pages with scrollview. Also you can create manage collection-view as horizontal/vertical.